# How can I get SQL to do the sensible thing without resorting to a query hint?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, performance, query-performance

I have two tables, `Items` and `Grouping`. `Items` has about 7 million rows whereas `Grouping` only has 300,000.

Of the two conditions on my query, the 'human obvious' thing is to evaluate `G.StatusID IN (1,2)` first. It seems obvious to do this first because:

- only 10% of rows fulfil the criteria about `StatusID` (I have checked, and SQL's statistics know this)
- `Grouping` has relatively few rows
- there is an index on `StatusID`

Those things combined mean that if the `G.StatusID IN (1,2)` condition is looked at, far fewer rows from `Items` have to be examined.

```
Select
    GroupingID,
    Sum (Amount) FullAmount
From
    Grouping G 
Join
    Items I
        -- With (INDEX(IX_Items_GroupingID))
        On G.GroupingID = I.GroupingID
Where
    I.ThingID Is Null
And
    G.StatusID IN (1,2)
Group By
    G.GroupingID
```

However SQL Server refuses to do this. It is reading the entirety of `Items` into memory, and suggests that I implement an index on ThingID. Implementing such an index does speed everything up, but I don't see why I should need to.

If I uncomment the index hint in the code above, SQL Server does as I want it to.

I'd prefer not to put the index hint into production. What is causing SQL Server to pick a slow plan?

(For background, around 25% of `Items` fulfil `I.ThingID Is Null`.)

[Slow plan on Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ-7caHoQ)

[Fast plan on Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJDw5aHim)

`Amount` is a column from `Items`

Comment: Hi, When adding extra information it is best to [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/220431/edit) the question instead of adding them in comments. I have done it for you this time

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to edit your index on `Grouping_ID` to include `ThingID` and `Amount` as per the comments, this will eliminate the Key Lookup in the second plan (76%).